# I want to load map inside my android application on webview within a fragment. I use following code below

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

```
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

where url : https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Hilton+Sydney/@lat,long,17.51z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x6b12ae3ef48720f1:0xe4cb86124df9b798!2sHilton+Sydney!8m2!3d-33.871915!4d151.208055!3m4!1s0x6b12ae3ef48720f1:0xe4cb86124df9b798!8m2!3d-33.871915!4d151.208055

It opens dialog box with suggestion for open URL in browse or map itself.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Android reads your Intent and provides the list of apps that can handle that Intent. Best solutions is that you use MapFragment to display maps

Comment: I agree, but i want to  display map on webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//        webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Hilton+Sydney/@-33.8719105,151.2058663,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x6b12ae3ef48720f1:0xe4cb86124df9b798!2sHilton+Sydney!3b1!8m2!3d-33.871915!4d151.208055!3m4!1s0x6b12ae3ef48720f1:0xe4cb86124df9b798!8m2!3d-33.871915!4d151.208055");
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating google map activity and in map view  pass your location's  latitude and logitude to it.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
  // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(yourlatitude, yourlongitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Hilton Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

hope this helps